# Trouble - Same Layout in Different Densities

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-emulator

I am testing my app in HVGA and WVGA800 resolutions both are Normal Screen, so I created images for medium and high density, but I can't understand why my text "Orientação" (title) in HVGA is decentralized compared to WVGA800, I coded with "dp" unit as below:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageCanadaNavBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/canada_navbar"
        android:onClick="imgTop_Click"  />       
   <ImageView 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/imageCanadaNavBar"
        android:src="@drawable/bg_viagem"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />                                
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"            
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"             
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="19sp"
        android:gravity="center|center_vertical"        
        android:layout_below="@id/imageCanadaNavBar" />    
    <ScrollView 
        android:id="@+id/scrollTextoDetalhe"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="7dp" 
        android:layout_below="@id/txtTitle">                       
        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/txtDetalhe"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"                       
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:paddingRight="25dp"
            android:paddingLeft="25dp"
            android:paddingBottom="17dp"
            android:paddingTop="17dp" />        
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: Comparison between WVGA800 and HVGA]

Comment: Could you also post the surrounding layout code? (Parent and sibling views)

Comment: @kabuko yes of course, I added my full xml layout above.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `sp (Scale-independent Pixels)` instead of `dp (Dentisy-Independent Pixels)`.

It's recommended use this for text size units.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Dimension

Comment: I tried sp instead dp but the effect is the same. I'm going crazy!

Answer (score 0):

Your margin and padding settings make it look centered in the one instance, even though it really isn't.

Change `android:gravity="center"` to `android:gravity="center|center_vertical"` and your problem should be fixed (you might have to adjust your margins and padding a bit).

Comment: I tested your hint but the layout are still wrong on HVGA device.

Comment: Did you remove the top margin?  I believe the centering is done after the margins, so having a top margin but no bottom one will shift everything down.  Not at home, so I can't double check, but I believe this is the case.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that instead of using a separate ImageView for your TextView's background, you actually set it as the background. You should also make sure that Drawable is a 9-patch so that it can be properly scaled and adjust your padding/margins. So instead of:

```
<ImageView 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/imageCanadaNavBar"
    android:src="@drawable/bg_viagem"
    android:scaleType="fitXY" />                                
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"            
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"             
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="19sp"
    android:gravity="center|center_vertical"        
    android:layout_below="@id/imageCanadaNavBar" />
```

You should have something like:

```
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"            
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="19sp"
    android:gravity="center|center_vertical"       
    android:background="@drawable/bg_viagem" 
    android:layout_below="@id/imageCanadaNavBar" />
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I separated all images to make a unique image in XML.

[image: New Layout]

Here is my final app
[Canada Destino](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.tobecreative.canadadestino&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwyLDEsImNvbS50b2JlY3JlYXRpdmUuY2FuYWRhZGVzdGlubyJd)